# I have pytorch installed in a environment but import torch produces an error

Tags: import, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtualenv, pytorch

I have anaconda python3 kernel with pytorch and numpy installed in the environment. In jupyter notebook first line 'import torch' produces error.

I am using anaconda navigator to launch jupyter notebook and enter my environment and see pytorch is installed but not being imported. Tried various dir extensions 'from torch... import * but more error

```
import torch

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-20507c95d9af> in <module>
      1 
----> 2 import torch
      3 
      4 

~/anaconda3/envs/udacity1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py in <module>
    100     pass
    101 
--> 102 from torch._C import *
    103 
    104 __all__ += [name for name in dir(_C)

ImportError: /home/frida/anaconda3/envs/udacity1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so.1: undefined symbol: nvrtcGetProgramLogSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add this to the end of my path to establish a 'backend ' for my notebook kernel. Thanks to Kris Stern!
-m ipykernel install --user

first get your kernel path with
(which python3)
then connect it using

sudo (your path)/anaconda3/bin/python3 -m ipykernel install --user